# How to apply CSS to all elements of a class based on their height?

Tags: sass, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a CSS transition to an image, I've followed the W3 schools example and can't work out why this example isn't working.

The hover settings are being applied but without any transition. My SCSS is as follows:

```
    .rolloverImageContainer {
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(#383838, 0.75);
  transition: 0.3;
}

.rolloverImageText {
  outline: 2px solid white;
  outline-offset: -30px;
}

.rolloverImageContainer:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give seconds `s` to the `transition-duration` property.

```
.rolloverImageContainer {
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(#383838, 0.75);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rolloverImageText {
  outline: 2px solid white;
  outline-offset: -30px;
}

.rolloverImageContainer:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put 's' on the transition period......

```
.rolloverImageContainer {
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(#383838, 0.75);
  transition: 0.3;
}
```

should be

```
.rolloverImageContainer {
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(#383838, 0.75);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```